# How to call functionA from functionB in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I don't have much experience with front-end development, so I will be really grateful for a simple solution in this case scenario:

```
functionA(value, name) {
   /*some code*/

   return (
     /*some code*/
   )
}

functionB() {
    /*some code*/
    //how to call functionA here?

}

const firstFunction = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('firstFunction'));


firstFunction.render(
   <functionA 2 Alex />
)
```

Here, I have functionA and functionB, as well as getting an element from the HTML file by id and making it render the return value from functionA.

My question is, in this case, how can I call functionA from functionB? I understand that they should be in the same parent together in order to do that, but then I encounter a problem with calling the needed functions in the .render().

EDIT: When I try to call , I get the following error:
[image]

SOLTUION:

```
functionA(value, name) {
   /*some code*/

   return (
     /*some code*/
   )
}

functionB() {
    /*some code*/
    //how to call functionA here?

}

App() {
    <functionA value=2 name='Alex'>
    <functionB>

}

const indexPage = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('indexPage '));


indexPage .render(
   <App />
)
```

for more detailed solution: [Invalid hook call when I try to call function in another function React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78008588/invalid-hook-call-when-i-try-to-call-function-in-another-function-react/78008663#78008663)

Answer (score 0):

`render()` will only [render one React node at a time](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#root-render). In order to have both function rendered in the `render()` method, you should wrap them both into another React node. Hope this can help!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated my post with the error I am getting, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

In React, UI Components are defined as functions in your case functionA and functionB.

First note, by convention components are named using PascalCase.

So assuming both functionA and functionB are intented to be UI Components they will become function FunctionA() {}  and function FunctionB {}

If you are using React version < 18:

you need to mount the components using ReactDOM library into a dom element, defined in an html file.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
);
const element = <FunctionA />;
root.render(element);
```

From here, you can compose components by either nesting them or rendering as siblings

```
...
const element = () => (
   <>
     <FunctionA />
     <FunctionB />
   </>
)
```

```
const element = () => (
   <>
    <FunctionA>
      <FunctionB />
    </FunctionA>
   </>
)
```

In this last example FunctionA can pass props to FunctionB to communicate between Parent and Child and FunctionB can send data up to the parent using callback props

I invite you to read more in the react official docs about sharing state between components [here](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated my post with the error I am getting, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

In React, they call "Component" not "function" (but in fact they are just functions)

In React, component has only one parameter, that is an object (usually called "props")

```
const ComponentA = (object)=>{
   const {value, name} = object
   ....
}
```

```
const ComponentB = ()=>{
  ...
  return (
     <>
         ... some html
         <ComponentA value={2} name="Alex" />
     </>

  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated my post with the error I am getting, please check it out

Comment: @РусланВасилев can you do a codesandbox link?